# Haskell files are not recognize by `haskell-mode`

Tags: emacs, font-lock, haskell-mode

I am fairly new to Emacs - transitioning from Neovim.
I have the following line in my config file:

```lisp
(use-package haskell-mode)
```

When I open any Haskell file, I see no effect, e.g., no syntax highlighting and in the lower right corner it says my major mode is `Fundamental` instead of `Haskell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely a duplicate question - please search and delete if so.

"Using a package" doesn't apply any mode to any particular buffers visiting any particular kind of file.

If `haskell-mode` is a major mode then adjust the value of variable `auto-mode-alist`, so that it has one or more associations that turn it on when the relevant file types are visited.

If it's a minor mode then enable it in on the major-mode hook, `haskell-mode-hook`.

---

**UPDATED** after comments by OP that `haskell-mode` is in `auto-mode-alist` by default:

If it appears to be in `auto-mode-alist` by default, then check whether something in your init file is causing this. Test by starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

If you see `haskell-mode` in `auto-mode-alist` *with* your init file and you don't see it *without* your init file, then something in your init file is putting it there. ;-)

If that's the case, and you don't see any syntax highlighting even when `haskell-mode` is used, then your question isn't about getting `haskell-mode` turned on; it's about not getting some highlighting that you expect even when that mode **is** on. Then check font-lock for that mode.

Comment: "turn it on when the relevant file types are visited" - I am under the impression that Emacs does that automatically. No? It is says so here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html, in the very begining.

Comment: "Likely a duplicate question - please search and delete if so." - I searched before posting and could not find anything. Probably did not use the correct keywords.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker: No, it doesn't, except for the file types associated with the extensions in the default value of `auto-mode-alist`. (`haskell-mode` is not in that default value.)

Comment: I beg to differ. `haskell-mode` is in the default value. I just checked. C-h and then v and then type `auto-mode-alist`, It has a line there like this: `("\\.[gh]s\\'" . haskell-mode)` --> Haskell files should be recognized by defaul.

Comment: If you see that immediately, when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file) then they've added that since Emacs 28.2. If you didn't try `emacs -Q` then do so. If you see it with your init file and you don't see it without your init file, then something in your init file is putting it there. ;-) If that's the case, and you don't see any syntax highlighting, then please specify this in your question. In that case the question isn't about getting  `haskell-mode` turned on; it's about not getting some highlighting that you expect even when that mode is on. Then check font-lock for that mode.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your `-Q` idea helped me pinpoint the problem in my config. Long story short: I forgot to specify `emacs-lisp` in of my `#+begin_src` blocks. Please convert your comment to an answer and I will accept it.